# Why, just after installing Gostscript 9.27 on my Mac OS 10.13, I can not print PDFs anymore?

Tags: mac, pdf, ghostscript

Just after installing Ghostscript-9.27 on Mac OS 10.13 (to work on Scribus), my printers refuse to print PDFs, while it prints other file formats. The printer indicates: Stopped - Failed to "Filter"

Is there a way to continue using Ghostscript and print PDF?
ou
How to uninstall Ghostscript from my Mac ?

Thank you in advance for your help 
Jean-François (I'm french and this message is translated by googletrad)